# WPF UserControl Focus

Tags: wpf, user-controls, focus

I have a `UserControl` subclass that contains a `Grid`, which in turn contains a couple `TextBlock`s and a `Border` (which also contains a `TextBlock`).  See code below.

```
    <UserControl x:Class="ProjectNS.MyUserControl"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
       xmlns:my="clr-namespace:ProjectNS"
       mc:Ignorable="d" 
       Height="49" Width="150" BottomResizeLocked="True" TopResizeLocked="True"  
       MoveLocks="Vertical" Margin="0,-4" Focusable="True">
        <my:MyUserControl.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="BorderStyle" TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                     AncestorType={x:Type my:GanttBar}}, Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" 
                     Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource 
                        SelectedGanttBarBackGroundBrush}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource 
                        SelectedGanttBarBorderBrush}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </my:MyUserControl.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label FontSize="8.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="4,0,0,0" Foreground="Green" />
            <Border Grid.Row="1" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1.5" Style="
            {StaticResource BorderStyle}" FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource 
             SelectedBorderStyle}" Focusable="True" >
                <Label FontSize="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Margin="0,2,0,0" />
            </Border>
            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="8.5" Grid.Row="2" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,4,0" Foreground="Red" />
        </Grid>
    </my:MyUserControl>
```

I'm trying to get the color of the embedded Border to change color when my `UserControl` receives focus, but I can't for the life of me figure out what actually receives focus when I click on the control.  I've tried using the `GotFocus` event for every control, and nothing fires once the program is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a DataTrigger on the property `IsKeyboardFocusWithin`. I'm not positive the exact syntax, but it should look something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
    <Style.Triggers>

        <!-- Will change Border color when KeyboardFocus inside Border -->
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
        </Trigger>

        <!-- Will change Border color when UserControl contains KeyboardFocus -->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
            AncestorType={x:Type local:MyUserControl}}, 
            Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
        </DataTrigger>

    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: I don't even know what is getting focus (the `UserControl`, any of the `TextBlock`s, or the `Border`).  If the `Border` is getting focus, then I would agree that this should work.  If the `Border` is not getting focus, how can I change its style when something else in the `UserControl` gets focus?

Comment: @kungfumath `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` will return true if the focus is inside ANY control that is inside the border. I'm not 100% sure that borders have that property, but if not you can use a `RelativeSource` binding to see if `UserControl.IsKeyboardFocusWithin` is true, which will return true if ANY control inside your UserControl has focus.

Comment: @kungfumath I added both bindings to my answer, and tested both to make sure they work

Comment: Okay, now I'm getting a run-time error that says that I can't apply a binding to `Trigger.Property`.  I see your code...  attempting.

Comment: @kungfumath A regular `Trigger` cannot use bindings. It is meant for use with a Property that exists on the currently styled object. If you want to use a Binding in a trigger, you need to use a `DataTrigger` (see second trigger in answer)

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  I'm getting nothing.  I'll edit my code to reflect what I now have.

Comment: It seems to work fine for me.... I had to remove the `FocusVisualStyle` from the Border though since it isn't in the code you posted. If you replace your TextBlocks with a TextBox, does it work? It could be that you have no focusable element inside your UserControl.

Comment: Yeah, it works with the TextBox rather than a TextBlock, but that enables selection of the text on the Border rather than having the text as decoration (editing will be performed in a pop-up panel for aesthetic purposes).  I've tried setting all of the controls as Focusable, but to no avail.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer since it works if the UC contains a "focusable" element.  Thank you.

Comment: So you want to change the border color if the control has focus, but you don't want to the control to have focus? I guess you can try using a Label instead of a TextBlock since Labels can have focus.

Comment: I want the user to be able to click on the control, but not select text or make changes.  When this happens, the control changes color to signify that it is "selected".  When the user "selects" another control, this one changes back to its previous color.  I tried with Labels, too, but it didn't work for me.